# Method not allowed in wso2 esb

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I need to add api service using wso2 api management or wso2 ei. i have a web api with ip:port format that have response via postman but when i add web api in api manager or wso2 ei in api menu and call published api via postman i get this error 
method not allowed and in log i have this error : main sequence executed for call to non-existent = /CardTransfer/
my API Source :

```
 <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="NoorService" context="/CardTransfer" version="v1" version-type="url">
<resource methods="POST">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="full">
        <property name="befor" value="befor"/>
     </log>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http uri-template="http://x.x.x.x:9110/"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
     <log level="full">
        <property name="after" value="after"/>
     </log>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
</resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request URL for the API resource you have created is:

```
https://<ip>:<port>/CardTransfer
```

the forward slash end of the API context should be omitted.

If the API resource contains a `url-mapping="/"`, the request URL would be:

```
https://<ip>:<port>/CardTransfer/
```

Comment: you are right . i change context="/" and my problem is solved

Comment: @behzad if it worked can you select it as the correct answer, so that it will be easy for others looking for correct answer.